# MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Users"

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mean-stack

Im learing the MEAN stack form a thinkster.io tutorial, and it seems that something went very wrong near the end of it. Node doesn't seem to find my schema despite the code looking like this:

**Users.js (model in ./models)**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
// some more code
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: {type: String, lowercase: true, unique: true},
    hash: String,
    salt: String
});
// then there are some UserSchema.methods.* here
mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

**app.js**

```
// some definitions
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27000/awsBase');

require('./models/Posts');
require('./models/Comments');
require('./models/Users');
require('./config/passport');

var routes = require('./routes/index.js');

var app = express();
// and so on
```

What am I missing? I will be very grateful for any help or insight.

Best regards,

Piotr

Answer (score 0):

i think you have made mistake in app.js
your model name is 'User' but you have used wrong model name i.e 'Users' in app.js

-->  require('./models/Users');

It should have been

---> require('./models/User');

Comment: Thanks for the tip, although as far as I understand, the require part is OK - it points to the valid Users.js file. As you can see [here](https://github.com/tigzytigz/flapper-news/blob/master/models/Posts.js) and [here](https://github.com/tigzytigz/flapper-news/blob/master/models/Comments.js) other models are defined as singulars and required as plurals,

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not where you are declaring the model, but when you are calling the model. Do you have a snippet in your controller that looks something like this that you could share?

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
User = mongoose.model('User');
...

User.find()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I do have a snippet similar to the one you provided, available [here](https://github.com/piotrjaw/flapper-news/blob/2f6613080747e0a9c9d1b5597ef6bcbade0c65e6/config/passport.js).

Comment: Umm okay that's a little strange. Can you put in a console.log(User) on line nine and report the result?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little late, but I ran into a similar error when trying to run 'npm start'. I'm just getting started on MEAN via the thinkster.io tutorial. In my case, changing this line in Users.js did the trick:

```
mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

change to:

```
mongoose.model('Users', UserSchema);
```

Hope this helps someone.